# Adding a document to a SharePoint list using a Ribbon button

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I have a SharePoint solution using a custom document library.  I need a way to allow users to added documents, but I need to specify the file name based on strict naming conventions.  I am currently trying to use a Sharepoint workflow, but there is some contention for document control. I was thinking I could write a ribbon button that would added the document, and immediately name it.  It looks like ribbon buttons calls javascript, but I not sure how to create a new document using a Javascript function.  Any suggestions or alternatives?

Comment: i am not getting well. can you elaborate more? what you  have tried?

Comment: I think basically I need to learn a way to add a document to a library using javascript.  

I am open to suggestions for alternative UIs for a user to add a document, and allow me to specify the file name programmaticly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a document using javascript, you just need to write a custom action [RibbonButton] that calls a method in some assembly that adds a new document to the desired document library following your rules. And if you can only add documents using a specific set of rules, make sure you disable the out of the box "Add Item" button on that custom document library.

You should check this link out: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

Hope it helps.